# TestNG: What do we mean when we say Run-time configuration is flexible in TEStNG

Tags: testng

TestNG: What do we mean when we say :

1. Run-time configuration is flexible in TestNG, how is it achived?
   Is it referring to grouping and @Test(enable=<>)?
2. Separate compile time test code from data info /run time configuration

Answer (score 1):

It means you can choose, at runtime, what tests will be run without having to change anything in the code.